# When do geometric morphisms lead to periodic adjoints?

Tags: topos-theory, adjoint-functors, infinity-topos-theory

This may be a naïve question but I've been unable to locate a reference that addresses it.  Any thoughts are appreciated!

Let $f:\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{S}$ be a cohesive morphism of toposes.  That is, we have an adjoint string of functors $f_!\dashv f^\ast \dashv f_\ast \dashv f^!$.

Are there interesting and/or nondegenerate examples where we have $f^! \dashv f_!$?  I'm willing to consider higher toposes, toposes with additional structure, etc.

This is partially motivated by a notational coincidence: in the setting of derived algebraic geometry, where $f_!$ and $f^!$ denote operations with compact support, we do have such an adjunction, albeit in the opposite direction.

More concretely, I am considering certain kinds of computation that share many properties with local geometric morphisms $(f_\ast, f^\ast, f_!)$, and for chaining such computations it would be advantageous to have some $f_! \dashv g \dashv f_\ast$.

It may be that I'm asking too much.  [Groth and Shulman](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.08084) construct a similar-looking adjoint cycle of period 6 in studying stable derivators, so additional "stitching" may be necessary for my approach to work.

Comment: In the even more restrictive case, when $f_!=f_*$ and $f^!=f^*$, you already get something nontrivial - quintessential localizations. They were studied by Johnstone in [1996](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1996/n8/2-08abs.html).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks for this reference!  In my problem I think there's no hope of having these equalities, but there are really important techniques and examples from this paper that may generalize.  For example, Johnstone constructs examples from monoids; using semirings may give examples of periodic adjoint quadruples.

Comment: Concerning chains of adjoints you might find something useful in the questions https://mathoverflow.net/q/242390/41291 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/46877/41291

Comment: About that most restrictive case, there is also the paper [Bireflectivity](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397598003545) by Freyd, O'Hearn, Power, Takeyama, Street and Tennent (1999)